# How can I get the values of an "enum" in a generic?

Tags: java, generics

How can I get the values of an "enum" in a generic?

```
public class Sorter<T extends Enum<?>> {
    public Sorter() {
        T[] result = T.values(); // <- Compilation error
    }
}
```

On the other hand, I can query the values() for Enum class:

```
enum TmpEnum { A, B }

public class Tmp {
    void func() {
        T[] result = TmpEnum.values(); // <- It works
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## `Class::getEnumConstants`

You cannot directly get it from `T` because generics are [erased](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) by the Java compiler so at runtime it is no longer known what `T` is.

What you can do is require a [`Class<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html) object as constructor parameter. From there you can get an array of the enum objects by calling [`Class::getEnumConstants`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants()).

```java
public class Sorter<T extends Enum<T>> {
    public Sorter(Class<T> clazz) {
        final T[] enumConstants = clazz.getEnumConstants();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another way is using interface

```
public interface Sorter{
    default public void sorting(){
         Sorter[] list=this.getClass().getEnumConstants();
    }
}
```

use

```
enum TmpEnum implements Sorter { A, B }
```